# Error: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update" - MySql

Tags: mysql

Cuando trato de hacer correr la consulta en phpMyAdmin me salta el siguiente error:

> Error
>   consulta SQL:
>
> ALTER TABLE descripciones_publicaciones_comunes ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion_comun 
>       FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion_comun) REFERENCES publicaciones_comunes (id)
>   MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
>
> 1005 - No puedo crear tabla `nombre_bd`.`descripciones_publicaciones_comunes` (Error: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") (Detalles…)

Aqui les dejo el script de mi consulta:

```
CREATE TABLE fotos_publicaciones_comunes
(
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    id_publicacion_comun VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    foto TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY (id_publicacion_comun)
) 
;


CREATE TABLE descripciones_publicaciones_comunes
(
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    id_publicacion_comun VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    descripcion VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY (id_publicacion_comun)
) 
;


CREATE TABLE foto_publicaciones_eventos
(
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    id_publicacion_evento VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    foto TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY (id_publicacion_evento)
) 
;


CREATE TABLE publicaciones_comunes
(
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    id_publicacion VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY (id_publicacion)
) 
;


CREATE TABLE publicaciones_eventos
(
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    id_publicacion VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    titulo_evento VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    descripcion_evento VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    fecha_inicio DATE NOT NULL,
    fecha_final DATE NOT NULL,
    hora_inicio TIME NOT NULL,
    hora_final TIME,
    direccion VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    ubicacion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    foto_portada TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY (id_publicacion)
) 
;


CREATE TABLE publicaciones
(
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    id_publicante VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    tipo_publicacion VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    fecha_publicacion TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    publicacion_visible TINYINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 
;





ALTER TABLE fotos_publicaciones_comunes ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion_comun 
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion_comun) REFERENCES publicaciones_comunes (id)
;

ALTER TABLE descripciones_publicaciones_comunes ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion_comun 
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion_comun) REFERENCES publicaciones_comunes (id)
;

ALTER TABLE foto_publicaciones_eventos ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion_evento 
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion_evento) REFERENCES publicaciones_eventos (id)
;

ALTER TABLE publicaciones_comunes ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion 
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion) REFERENCES publicaciones (id)
;

ALTER TABLE publicaciones_eventos ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion 
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion) REFERENCES publicaciones (id)
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenías duplicado el nombre de la **restricción**, o sea después de `add constraint`. Es un nombre que hay que declarar obligatoriamente pero que vos no lo usas, si no mysql. Fijate que le puse un número a cada uno. Y también te comenté el `KEY(claveForanea)`, mira:

```
CREATE TABLE fotos_publicaciones_comunes
(
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    id_publicacion_comun VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    foto TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -- KEY (id_publicacion_comun)
) 
;


CREATE TABLE descripciones_publicaciones_comunes
(
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    id_publicacion_comun VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    descripcion VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -- KEY (id_publicacion_comun)
) 
;


CREATE TABLE foto_publicaciones_eventos
(
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    id_publicacion_evento VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    foto TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -- KEY (id_publicacion_evento)
) 
;


CREATE TABLE publicaciones_comunes
(
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    id_publicacion VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -- KEY (id_publicacion)
) 
;


CREATE TABLE publicaciones_eventos
(
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    id_publicacion VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    titulo_evento VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    descripcion_evento VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    fecha_inicio DATE NOT NULL,
    fecha_final DATE NOT NULL,
    hora_inicio TIME NOT NULL,
    hora_final TIME,
    direccion VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    ubicacion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    foto_portada TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -- KEY (id_publicacion)
) 
;


CREATE TABLE publicaciones
(
    id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    id_publicante VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    tipo_publicacion VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    fecha_publicacion TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    publicacion_visible TINYINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 
;





ALTER TABLE fotos_publicaciones_comunes ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion_comun1 
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion_comun) REFERENCES publicaciones_comunes (id)
;

ALTER TABLE descripciones_publicaciones_comunes ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion_comun2 
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion_comun) REFERENCES publicaciones_comunes (id)
;

ALTER TABLE foto_publicaciones_eventos ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion_evento3 
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion_evento) REFERENCES publicaciones_eventos (id)
;

ALTER TABLE publicaciones_comunes ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion4 
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion) REFERENCES publicaciones (id)
;

ALTER TABLE publicaciones_eventos ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion5 
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion) REFERENCES publicaciones (id)
;
```

Comment: Entiendo, pero al agregar los numeros a las restricciones y al comentar el `KEY(claveForanea)`, no afecta a la estructura que quiero que este en la base de datos?

Comment: no afecta, por que para declarar la `clave primaria` basta con la instrucción `primary key (id)`. Y los nombres de las restricciones, como te dije, es solo un nombre que usa el sistema mysql, vos no lo usas, vos cuando quieras referirte a la `clave foranea` vas a usar el nombre de la `clave foranea`, por ej. la `clave foranea` de `fotos_publicaciones_comunes` es `id_publicacion_comun`

Comment: Estoy viendo que en `publicaciones` no tenes declarada la `clave foranea` `id_publicante` que igualmente tampoco tenes la tabla `publicante`

Comment: y otra cosa, te piden que las `claves` sean `varchar`? Por que si no te conviene que sean `int` con `auto increment`

Comment: si, en `id_publicante` ira el id de la persona quien realizo la publicacion, no lo coloque porque no queria que se haga muy largo y tambien porque el error no era ahi. Gracias por la observacion.

Answer (score 0):

los problemas que tienes son 2, pero son prácticamente los mismos:

```
ALTER TABLE fotos_publicaciones_comunes ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion_comun <---------- 1)
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion_comun) REFERENCES publicaciones_comunes (id)
;

ALTER TABLE descripciones_publicaciones_comunes ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion_comun <-- 1)
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion_comun) REFERENCES publicaciones_comunes (id)
;

-------------------------------------------

ALTER TABLE publicaciones_comunes ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion <----- 2)
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion) REFERENCES publicaciones (id)
;

ALTER TABLE publicaciones_eventos ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion <------2)
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion) REFERENCES publicaciones (id)
;
```

Tienes esos nombres repetidos... solo cambia los nombres de los constraints y funcionará sin problemas.

por ejemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE fotos_publicaciones_comunes ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion_comun1
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion_comun) REFERENCES publicaciones_comunes (id)
;

ALTER TABLE descripciones_publicaciones_comunes ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion_comun2
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion_comun) REFERENCES publicaciones_comunes (id)
;

ALTER TABLE publicaciones_comunes ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion1
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion) REFERENCES publicaciones (id)
;

ALTER TABLE publicaciones_eventos ADD CONSTRAINT FK_id_publicacion2
FOREIGN KEY (id_publicacion) REFERENCES publicaciones (id)
;
```